# running .kmodel model testing on googlecolab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

i have a code to running model predictions using .h5 model, it is possible to running the model predictions using a .kmodel (k210)?

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the trained model

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/model/model (2).h5')

# Load and preprocess the input image

def preprocess_image(image_path):
image = Image.open(image_path)
image = image.resize((224, 224))  # Resize the image to match the model's input shape
image = image.convert('RGB')  # Convert the image to RGB color mode
image = np.array(image)  # Convert PIL image to NumPy array
image = image / 255.0  # Normalize pixel values to the range of 0 and 1
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)  # Add batch dimension
return image

# Make predictions

def predict_image(image_path):
image = preprocess_image(image_path)
predictions = model.predict(image)
return predictions
```

ive been asking from chat gpt it is say that i must convert it to h5 or tflite but i need testing the .kmodel, maybe i need some references from kmodel testing